# How can I automatically disable other rows using jquery after clicking a button from another row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each table row in a table contains a table data that has an edit button. A table row that is enabled must be disabled when the user clicks the edit button in another row, then the row of that edit button which you recently clicked is enabled.

```
HTML: 

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="edit" id="editBtn" class="edit"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><span class="edit">Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="edit" id="editBtn" class="edit"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="edit" id="editBtn" class="edit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  JQUERY:
    $(function() {
       $( "table" ).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
          $(this).removeClass('edit');
          $(this).addClass('removeEdit');
            $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
            });

        $( "table" ).on( "click", ".removeEdit", function() {
          $(this).removeClass('removeEdit');
          $(this).addClass('edit');
            $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
            });
```

Comment: can you please share a code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62hughdj/14/)

```
$(function() {
  $( "table" ).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
      $('table td').removeClass('removeEdit');
      $('table td').addClass('edit');
      $('table tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
      $(this).removeClass('edit');
      $(this).addClass('removeEdit');
      $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
  });

  $( "table" ).on( "click", ".removeEdit", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('removeEdit');
      $(this).addClass('edit');
      $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

Comment: you mean to replace span with button ?

Comment: You're a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $( "table" ).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
    
     var self =$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    
     $("table tr").find('input[type=checkbox]').not(self).prop('disabled',true);
    
      self.each(function(){
        $(this).prop('disabled', !$(this).prop('disabled'));
     });
    
    
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="edit" value ="Edit" id="editBtn" class="edit">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input type="submit" name="edit" value ="Edit" id="editBtn" class="edit">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input type="submit" name="edit" value ="Edit" id="editBtn" class="edit" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
     <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled>
    </td> 
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="edit" value ="Edit" id="editBtn" class="edit">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actualy you are doing it wrong because you are giving the class edit to every td element. That's why i have use the .last() in my code